# Is there a way to relay git credential helpers over ssh?

Tags: git, github, ssh-agent

I have GCM set up on my Windows machine, and I have git in WSL configured to access GCM on the Windows side.  But when I SSH to another host, it's not able to use the token that GCM manages.

Is there a way to relay the remote git's credential request back to the origin's GCM, similar to how ssh-agent is able to forward access to keys to a remote session?

Comment: Not without modifying ssh, no. Agent requests go over a control channel and use a data format defined by ssh. Even if you could, it's not clear whether this would accomplish anything, since the credential verification happens at startup before Git gets involved, and is run when ssh attempts to "log in", so you'd have to have something special happen in the host's sshd.

Comment: Meanwhile, instead of involving ssh this way, consider making gcm itself able to use ssh (and/or sshfs) to, on the other host, ssh back to the host that has the credentials, obtain them, and present them over an https connection.

Answer (score 1):

In general, no.  The SSH protocol does not allow arbitrary programs on the client to be run, because that's typically a security risk.

However, you could forward your SSH agent over to the server with `ssh -A` and instead use SSH to access the repository instead of HTTPS.  If you want to do that without modifying the existing repository, you can add this to your `~/.gitconfig`:

```
[url "git@github.com:"]
  insteadOf = https://github.com/
```